# I am facing problem installing SSL certificates from godaddy in xampp which is installed on aws

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

I have done everything like I have edited vhost file given the correct directory but also done the changes in httpd-ssl.conf file Please guide me step by step how can I install SSL of godaddy in xampp on my server.

Comment: Please check [help/on-topic] for topics that are on-topic here, and [ask], which will help you when you ask the question on a site where configuration of webservers are on-topic

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: This question hits multiple reasons to close: 1-asking for documentation 2-not programming related (see also the [tag:apache] tag description). 3-doesn't state clearly what you did (obviously, you did not do "everything")